# Admin User Permissions Changed By Accident

Tags: admin, admin-panel, user-roles, admin-user

I accidentally changed Administrator User permissions in admin. Only Store Tab is accessible.

[image]

Can't Access any other tab.

Answer (score 0):

Solution: I found this amazing solution. Please follow.

https://community.magento.com/t5/Magento-2-x-Technical-Issues/Admin-roles-have-been-changed-by-accident-no-none-of-us-can-do/td-p/460613

1. Create a mysqldump of the current database
2. reset all admin users Truncating three Table using.

   TRUNCATE TABLE admin_user;
   TRUNCATE TABLE authorization_role;
   TRUNCATE TABLE authorization_rule;

3: Insert new User in with All Roles , Run below three Command

```
  INSERT INTO admin_user (user_id, firstname, lastname, email, username, password, created, modified, logdate, lognum, reload_acl_flag, is_active, extra, rp_token, rp_token_created_at, interface_locale, failures_num, first_failure, lock_expires, refresh_token) VALUES (1, 'Amit', 'Emizen', 'emizen@example.com', 'amit_emizen', '45cf9053530ceb9fde49794d9e6d81fd2ce481b0136067986a5c9bc139a7d08f:FivE4hOQqPtW1xdE:2', '2020-10-11 10:48:31', '2019-09-09 13:20:42', '2020-10-11 13:20:42', 46, 0, 1, '{"configState":{"contact_contact":"1","web_default_layouts":"0","web_default":"1","web_secure":"1","web_seo":"1","web_unsecure":"1","wishlist_wishlist_link":"1","wishlist_email":"1","wishlist_general":"1","admin_emails":"0","admin_startup":"0","dev_front_end_development_workflow":"1","dev_restrict":"0","dev_debug":"1","dev_template":"0","sw_megamenu_general":"1","newsletter_general":"1","newsletter_subscription":"1","dev_js":"0","admin_security":"0","admin_url":"0","admin_dashboard":"0","admin_captcha":"0","sw_megamenu_custom_links":"1","sw_megamenu_cat_labels":"1","cms_wysiwyg":"1","catalog_frontend":"1","catalog_fields_masks":"0","catalog_review":"1","catalog_productalert":"1","catalog_productalert_cron":"1","catalog_placeholder":"1","catalog_recently_products":"1","catalog_product_video":"0","catalog_price":"0","catalog_layered_navigation":"1","catalog_search":"0","catalog_seo":"0","catalog_navigation":"1","catalog_downloadable":"1","catalog_custom_options":"0","layered_navigation_module":"1","layered_navigation_general":"1","carriers_flatrate":"1","carriers_freeshipping":"1","carriers_tablerate":"1","carriers_temando":"1","carriers_ups":"1","carriers_usps":"1","carriers_fedex":"1","carriers_dhl":"1","shipping_origin":"1","shipping_shipping_policy":"1","tax_vertex_settings":"1","tax_classes":"1","tax_calculation":"1","tax_defaults":"1","tax_display":"1","tax_cart_display":"1","tax_sales_display":"1","tax_weee":"1","tax_vertex_seller_info":"0","tax_vertex_delivery_terms":"0","tax_avaiable_shipping_product_codes":"0","tax_vertex_logging":"0","dev_grid":"0","dev_static":"0","dev_image":"0","dev_css":"0","dev_translate_inline":"0","general_store_information":"1","general_single_store_mode":"1","general_locale":"1","general_region":"1","general_country":"1","productinquiry_general_option":"1","productinquiry_google_captcha":"1","productinquiry_email_setting":"1","trans_email_ident_general":"1","product_attachment_general":"1","product_attachment_display_configuration":"1"}}', NULL, NULL, 'en_US', 0, NULL, NULL, NULL);
    
    INSERT INTO authorization_role (role_id, parent_id, tree_level, sort_order, role_type, user_id, user_type, role_name) VALUES (1, 0, 1, 1, 'G', 0, '2', 'Administrators'), (2, 1, 2, 0, 'U', 1, '2', 'admin');
    
    INSERT INTO authorization_rule (rule_id, role_id, resource_id, privileges, permission) VALUES (1, 1, 'Magento_Backend::all', NULL, 'allow');
```

4. now flush Magento cache

   php bin/magento cache:flush ;

   php bin/magento cache:clean ;
5. You have to create a fresh Admin User after running all queries.

   php bin/magento admin:user:create --admin-user="admin" --admin-password="admin123" --admin-email="jasvir@yourmail.com" --admin-firstname="Jasvir" --admin-lastname="Singh"

All Done.

Answer (score 0):

Please create new admin user by command line and then assign role to existing user.

```
$ bin/magento admin:user:create --admin-user="newadmin" --admin-password="yourpassword" --admin-email="mail@example.com" --admin-firstname="newAdmin" --admin-lastname="newAdmin"
```

You could have a look into it:

https://community.magento.com/t5/Magento-2-x-Technical-Issues/Admin-roles-have-been-changed-by-accident-no-none-of-us-can-do/td-p/460613

Flush Cache with:

```
php bin/magento cache:flush ;
```

Check the logs for further debugging, may be it can help you out in the actual reason.